# SQLAlchemy: filtering multiple column values in a subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQL, I can use the `IN` operator with a subquery like so:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE (t1.some_int, t1.some_string) IN (
    SELECT id, name FROM t2
)
```

But I am unable to translate this to an SQLAlchemy query. As far as I know, the `in_` method only works on one column. Is there any way to replicate this functionality in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JOIN instead of subquery. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.some_int = t2.id AND t1.some_string = t2.name
```

And in sqlalchemy:

T1:

```
class T1(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 't1'

    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    id = Column(u'id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_int = Column('some_int', Integer)
    some_str = Column('some_str', String(45))

    def __init__ (self, some_int, some_str):
        self.some_int = some_int
        self.some_str = some_str
```

T2:

```
class T2(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 't2'

    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    id = Column(u'id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(45))
    data = Column('data', String(45))

    def __init__ (self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
```

In source code:

```
data = session.query(T1).join(T2, and_(T1.some_int == T2.id, T1.some_string == T2.name)).all()
```

In result engine generates sql:

```
SELECT t1.some_int AS t1_some_int, t1.id AS t1_id FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.some_int = t2.id AND t1.some_str = t2.name
```